# Convert.ChangeType shows input FormatException on a different language

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

In my database I store a value's type and value in strings, then convert it back as a dynamic object when needed. Though the conversion seems to fail when using the french-Canadian route.

Below are the steps to quickly recreate the error using the ASP.NET Core Web Application (2.1 MVC) template :

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
            new CultureInfo("en-CA"),
            new CultureInfo("fr-CA")
        };

        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-CA");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        options.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
        {
            new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider()
        };
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRouter(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapMiddlewareRoute("{culture=en-CA}/{*mvcRoute}", subApp =>
        {
            subApp.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

            subApp.UseMvc(mvcRoutes =>
            {
                mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{culture=en-CA}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[Route("{culture=en-CA}")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    public dynamic Index()
    {
        return Convert.ChangeType("1,0", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"));
    }
}
```

I noticed the following when I was playing around with the value string:

**GET / or GET /en-CA**

```
"1"   => "1.0"
"1.0" => "1.0"
"1,0" => "10.0"
```

**GET /fr-CA**

```
"1"   => "1.0"
"1.0" => Error
"1,0" => "1.0"
```

I don't want to localize the numbers, so how do I output everything in just decimal notation (1.0)?

Comment: 1.0 is not a supported format to this specific region... In french, the decimal is not a dot but a comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're converting to/from string at the application-database boundary, pass `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the third parameter to `Convert.ChangeType`.

For example, when reading from the database:

```
Convert.ChangeType("1.0", Type.GetType("System.Decimal"), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

...and when saving to the database:

```
Convert.ChangeType(1.0M, typeof(string), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Then the database will always have the same format.